# Gatling folder path changed by Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, gatling

Local build generates reports in the correct folder: target/results
but when building using Jenkins it puts them in target/gatling/results

This is an issue because now the gatling plugin for Jenkins is unable to find the reports

I can't find where it sets the path

Comment: did you override the `resultsFolder` property of the gatling plugin in your `pom.xml`? Default value [is](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/extensions/maven_plugin.html) effectively `target/gatling/results`

Comment: yes i changed it to target/results. the only thing that's there is the simulation.txt. everything else is under gatling/results

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to configure the results folder path for the gatling plugin for Jenkins. It will look for any folder containing a Gatling Simulation, so your configuration doesn't matter.

If you can't make it work and think it is a bug, provide us your jenkins version, gatling-plugin version and gatling version.

You can use our mailing list to post questions specific to Galing.

Comment: Jenkins version 1.642.4, Gatling version 2.1.7

Comment: Gatling plugin version 1.2.0